# Expand and Collapse in treecolumn in advancedgrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, tree, advanceddatagrid

Can anyone say how I can expand and collapse treeColumn value in advancedGrid in Flex under a particular parent. I just want to expand and collapse only the children under a particular parent node in the grid.
Thanks in Advance
Vishnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can expand/collapse a specific item simply giving this statement to your adg:

```
adg.expandItem(<your_item>, !adg.isItemOpen(<your_item>))
```

your_item is the item of your dataProvider that you want to expand/collapse in your adg

Comment: Is there any way to know whether any item in advanced data grid is in expand or collapse state?

Comment: hi, i'm not sure to have understood your question. I try to answer: you colund write a boolean method which loops for each row of the dataProvider and makes this control: adg.isItemOpen(youDp.getItemAt(i)) == true....if you get all controls true this means that all items are expanded...obviously you can do the same control for the opposite case. Hope this helps...let me know!

Comment: I will make it clear to you. I have an adg which have a tree structure (hierarchical). I want to know whether the item is in collapse (+) state or in expand state (-).

Comment: Once again thanks @marcocb. The above scenario worked for me.